# CSS fixed element causes jump to the top

Tags: css

Please have a look at this website https://ebooks.am
After clicking a table row, a fixed positioned sidebar opens.
The problem is that the sidebar causes webpage to jump to the top. 

How can I avoid this?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i inspect the body while clicking, it gains that "disable-scroll" class.

```
position: fixed!important;
```

that css line prevents scrolling but also scrolls to the top.

Comment: thank you. that's right. And how is it possible to prevent that scrolling to top and also body scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: fixed;` not to the `body`, but to the `.sidebar.sidebar-move-to-left` element.

or

on the `.disable-scroll` selector, add `position: relative;` instead of `position: fixed!important;`. But **disable-scroll** naming loses its definition ^-^.